# DeflateStream / GZipStream to CryptoStream and vice versa

Tags: c#, rijndael, gzipstream, deflatestream, cryptostream

I want to to compress and encrypt a file in one go by using this simple code:

```
public void compress(FileInfo fi, Byte[] pKey, Byte[] pIV)
{
    // Get the stream of the source file.
    using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
    {                
        // Create the compressed encrypted file.
        using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi.FullName + ".pebf"))
        {
            using (CryptoStream encrypt = new CryptoStream(outFile, Rijndael.Create().CreateEncryptor(pKey, pIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (DeflateStream cmprss = new DeflateStream(encrypt, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
                {
                    // Copy the source file into the compression stream.
                    inFile.CopyTo(cmprss);
                    Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.", fi.Name, fi.Length.ToString(), outFile.Length.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following lines will restore the encrypted and compressed file back to the original:

```
public void decompress(FileInfo fi, Byte[] pKey, Byte[] pIV)
{
    // Get the stream of the source file.
    using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
    {
        // Get original file extension, for example "doc" from report.doc.gz.
        String curFile = fi.FullName;
        String origName = curFile.Remove(curFile.Length - fi.Extension.Length);

        // Create the decompressed file.
        using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName))
        {
            using (CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(inFile, Rijndael.Create().CreateDecryptor(pKey, pIV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (DeflateStream dcmprss = new DeflateStream(decrypt, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {                    
                    // Copy the uncompressed file into the output stream.
                    dcmprss.CopyTo(outFile);
                    Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fi.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works also with GZipStream.

Comment: @CSharpie: Yes; he's writing to the stream.

Comment: BTW, `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`.

Comment: What's the exception stack trace?

Comment: After correcting the code, vice versa works also now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decompressing stream is expected to be [read from](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/System/IO/compression/DeflateStream.cs,61), not written to.  (unlike a `CryptoStream`, which supports all four combinations of read/write and encrypt/decrypt)

You should create the `DeflateStream` around a `CryptoStreamMode.Read` stream around the input file, then copy from that directly to the output stream.

Comment: @zaqk: Please update your question with the corrected code so that the first mistake isn't muddling things up.

Comment: @zaqk: You need to make the CryptoStream read from the input stream, not write to the output stream.

Comment: @zaqk: That's completely wrong.  You need to create both streams around eachother and the **input** file, then copy directly to the output stream.

Comment: https://github.com/ShomreiTorah/Libraries/blob/master/ShomreiTorah.Common/Updates/UpdateFile.cs#L139-L145